# Extract number from a formatted string(dropdownlist)

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to extract an integer from a string(selectedtext from dropdownlist) using substring. The number is between parenthesis, this is my code, but it keeps saying length cannot be zero, which I guess means that it can't find the parenthesis, even though they are there. An example of a value from my dropdownlist would be Test(99) or Teehee(1)

```
int selectedValue = int.Parse(values.SelectedText.Substring(values.SelectedText.IndexOf("(") + 1, values.SelectedText.IndexOf(")") - values.SelectedText.IndexOf("(") - 1)));
```

Comment: Your code is much more readable if you use multiple lines.

Comment: Although very verbose, your code works with the two examples you provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a regular expression for this.

**Pattern Demonstration**

https://regex101.com/r/gH3xK2/1

**Pattern**

```
\(([^)]*)\)
```

**Example Usage**

```
  Regex.Match("Test(99)", @"\(([^)]*)\)").Groups[1].Value
```

Answer (score 0):

If your number is always an Integer you can use `Regex` for it

```
var resultNumber = Regex.Match(values.SelectedText, @"\d+").Value;
```

and then use `int.parse`